# Connect SQL Server 2008 through Management Studio Express 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to connect SQL Server 2008 through Management Studio Express 2005. I have some limitations of Dot Net Framework upgrade on the client machine thats why trying to access it through 2005. I already implemented this solution:

**FIX: You may experience problems when you use SQL Server Management Studio in SQL Server 2005 to connect to an instance of SQL Server 2008**

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/946127

But its not working. I have installed a Management studio express 2005 SP4. But its doing trouble. It connects the 2008 Database server but when i tries to view the table through design view it throws an error message "Unspecified error". Where as i am able to view table records by making a query request.

I am really stuck. Please help me out.

Regards,

F. Ahmed

Answer (score 0):

The backward compatibility for client tools in SQL server 2008 is not as good as we wanted to be... Sorry.